# create plots based on radio button selection R Shiny

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I'm trying to create a `Shiny` App. The user interface `UI.R` looks just fine but I'm having issues with `server.R`. Basically I want a different plot output depending on which `radio` option the user selects.

The user may choose option `A`, `B`, or `C`. I want to draw a histogram if user selects option `A`, bar graph for `B`, and a pie chart for option `C` but I don't know how to code the condition? Is it like an `if-else` statement? I've been struggling for hours! Here's my code sample:

```
output$plots <- renderPlot({    
   if selection == 'A'
      # plot histogram
   if selection == 'B'
      # plot bar chart
   if selection == 'C'
      # plot pie chart
})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use switch to determine the behaviour based on the selection:

```
library(shiny)
myData <- runif(100)
plotType <- function(x, type) {
  switch(type,
         A = hist(x),
         B = barplot(x),
         C = pie(x))
}
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    radioButtons("pType", "Choose plot type:",
                 list("A", "B", "C")),
    plotOutput('plot')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({ 
       plotType(myData, input$pType)
    })
  }
))
```