# Create input$selection to subset data AND radiobuttons to choose plot type in Shiny

Tags: r, switch-statement, shiny, subset

I've been trying to utilize shiny to create several visualizations for several different classes of data. Last night I was able to subset data but I do not know how to switch plot types with this data.
I have the following data frame:

```
Hours<-c(2,3,4,2,1,1,3)
Project<-c("a","b","b","a","a","b","a")
cd=data.frame(Project,Hours)
```

### server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(lattice)

# Define shiny server
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

#Simple test plot
pdata=subset(cd, Project==input$proj)
plotType <- function(x, type) {
  switch(type,
         A = hist(x),
         B = barplot(x),
         C = pie(x))
}
  output$testPlot <- renderPlot({ 
    plotType(pdata, input$pType)
 })
 })
```

### ui.R

```
library(shiny)
ulist=levels(cd$Project)
names(ulist) = ulist
# Sidebar with a slider input for the number of bins
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  # Application title
  headerPanel("Project Data"),

  sidebarPanel(
    #select project
selectInput("proj", "Project:",ulist)
  ),

  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
   plotOutput("testPlot")
  )))
```

I'd like to incorporate the following code from jdharrison to the ui file:

```
  ui = bootstrapPage(
     radioButtons("pType", "Choose plot type:",
             list("A", "B", "C")),
plotOutput('plot')
```

The following is a link to his post which I'm trying to incorporate:
[create plots based on radio button selection R Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633662/create-plots-based-on-radio-button-selection-r-shiny)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `reactive` functions.

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
ulist=levels(cd$Project)
names(ulist) = ulist
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Project Data"),
  sidebarPanel(
    radioButtons("pType", "Choose plot type:",
                 list("A", "B", "C")),
    selectInput("proj", "Project:",ulist)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("testPlot")
  )
)
)
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(lattice)

# Define shiny server
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  pdata <- reactive({
    subset(cd, Project==input$proj)
  }
  )
  plotType <- reactive({
    switch(input$pType,
           A = hist,
           B = barplot,
           C = pie)
  })
  output$testPlot <- renderPlot({ 
    plotType()(pdata()[["Hours"]])
  })
})
```

[image]