# How to render different plot output types in R Shiny dependent of user input?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

In R Shiny I'd like to render different plot output types depending of the ticked radiobutton. This is easily implementable as seen in: [create plots based on radio button selection R Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633662/create-plots-based-on-radio-button-selection-r-shiny). Now taking this approach further, how to implement this with different output types such as dygraphs and amCharts? An attempt of what I am trying to achieve:

```
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)
library(amCharts)

myData <- runif(100)
myData <- ts(runif(72,0,10), start=c(2009, 1), end=c(2014, 12), frequency=12) 
myData 

outType <- function(x,type){
  switch(type,
         A = renderPlot({ hist(x)}),
         B = renderDygraph({ barplot(x)}),
         C = amChartsOutput({ pie(x)}))
}

plotOut <- function(type,plotlabel,data){
  switch(type,
         A = plotOutput(plotlabel,data),
         B = dygraph(plotlabel,data),
         C = plotOutput(plotlabel,data))
}

runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    radioButtons("pType", "Choose plot type:",
                 list("A", "B", "C")),
    plotOut('A','plot',myData)
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {
    observe({
      type <<- input$pType
      output$plot <- outType(myData, input$pType)  
    })
  }
))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that. In `server`:

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
  validate(need(input$pType=="A", message=FALSE))
  hist(myData)
})
output$dygraph <- renderDygraph({
  validate(need(input$pType=="B", message=FALSE))
  barplot(myData)
})
```

In `ui`:

```
conditionalPanel('input.pType=="A"', plotOutput("plot"))
conditionalPanel('input.pType=="B"', dygraphOutput("dygraph"))
```

Perhaps the conditional panels are not needed, since `plotOutput("plot")` will render nothing is `pType` is not `A`, and `dygraphOutput("dygraph")` will render nothing is `pType` is not `B`.